# How to increase capture default camera image quality

Tags: java, android, kotlin, camera

I am using default camera and capturing image. we have converted Base64 image after converting image quality is blur and image size getting very low below 50kb. Can you please help how to increase image better quality with Base64 format. I have attached my code please edit and give solution.

```
 private val getCameraImage = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview()) { bitmap ->
    try {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream)
            val byteArray: ByteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()

            encodedPhoto = Base64Utils.encode(byteArray)
            Toast.makeText(this.activity, "Image uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
            sales_invoice_image.background =
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.color.syncBar)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this.activity, "Something went wrong, Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
        }
    } catch (e: NullPointerException) {

    }
}
```

Comment: base64 encoding does not affect image quality.

Comment: Then how will you upload server base64 format

Comment: Please any one else help me

Comment: You are using `TakePicturePreview`. This gives a low-resolution image. If you want a full-resolution image, use `TakePicture`. However, you will not be able to use base64 encoding, because the image is going to be too large. Plus, base64 encoding has been obsolete for around 20 years. Upload the image directly to your server, such as [by using OkHttp and a suitable `RequestBody`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/07/05/multipart-upload-okttp-uri.html).

Comment: ha ok, how will be convert bitmap.

Comment: Getting Launch error,  granted -> {
                getCameraImage.launch()
            }